# Java "Create New" window

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I'm relatively new to GUI with Java and I have a JFrame with a simple menu bar with your typical create new button(Like create new file and stuff). I want to have it so when I select this button another window pops up and it has several things to fill out after which you select an ok button or a cancel button. Then the focus is returned to the main JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect job for a [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). [Dialog tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: But can you setup the Dialog where you can input over 10 different things in different JTextFields and labeled with different JLabels

Comment: @Brandon Yes. A `JDialog` has pretty much the same versatility as a `JFrame`.